# Jquery Cycle plugin rotating youtube videos not displaying correctly in Safari

Tags: css, overflow, jquery-cycle, safari

I have a Jquery Cycle plugin rotating youtube videos and it's not displaying correctly in Safari desktop.  I have tested on IE, FF, Chrome & mobile Safari with no issues.

It seems as if the overflow:hidden/auto property isn't working. Check out the link in Safari: http://www.tweedstudios.com/!/broadcast3.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the end of the URL's for the iframe's:

&wmode=opaque

`http://www.youtube.com/embed/Kx3xVE2tU6c?rel=0&autoplay=0&controls=1&wmode=opaque`

Comment: Thanks Lucuma, &wmode=opaque worked perfectly! Been fighting this for over a week...

Comment: Glad to help.. Anytime you deal with flash and css, make sure and check the wmode values.  <http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html#main_Using_Window_Mode__wmode__values_>